# how to create a button that plays a mp3 google tts

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech, google-translate, html5-audio

i'm new here but i hope you can help me.

i'm trying to create a button that plays the text to speech mp3 that google generates. i'm creating a translator, so, what i want is to do something like google translate is (in some way).

i've tried with javascript and actionscript but i couldn't make it work.

i have this javascript function:

```
function audio () {
    // here i get the word that i want to hear
    texto = document.getElementById('txt-result-palabra').innerHTML;
    // now i get the language
    idioma = document.getElementById("id-traducir-palabra").value;
    url = "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?q=";
    url += texto;
    url += "&tl=";
    url += idioma;
    }
```

so, with this function i actually have the url of the google tts for some word, but i don't know how to embed it, o which is the best way to do it. i mean, i can embed it with javascript, but i'm not sure if it's gonna work since the file that google generates is an mp3.

and i need this mp3 to be played onClick of an image...

i also wonder if it could be done with html5.

if anyone knows any solution i'd appreciate it a lot!

thanks in advance and have a great day!!!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have the url to the MP3, you need to append to the document

```
<audio autoplay="autoplay">
  <source src="url_to_google_tts.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

...

```
var audioObj = document.createElement("audio");
audioObj.autoplay = "autoplay";

var sourceObj = document.createElement("source");
sourceObj.src = "url_to_google.mp3";
sourceObj.type= "audio/mpeg";
audioObj.appendChild(sourceObj);

document.body.appendChild(audioObj);
```

Comment: hi ItzWarty! thanks for answering!!!

my problem is that i construct the mp3 url dynamically with javascript. so, how could assign the result of the funcion to the src?

thanks again!!!

Comment: it works fine, the problem is that not every browser accept mp3 with html5, and this is not good. i wonder if it's possible to do something similar with flash? thanks!

Comment: sole, how can you get the mp3 since it is generated dynamically by google as well? Would appreciate some help! Thanks.